# Playing remote audio files in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, audio, audio-streaming, python-module

I'm looking for a solution to easily play remote **.mp3** files. I have looked at "pyglet" module which works on local files, but it seems it can't handle remote files. I could temporary download the **.mp3** file but that's not reccomended due to how large the **.mp3** files could appear to be.

I rather want it to be for cross-platform instead of Windows-only etc.

Example, playing a audio file from:

> http://example.com/sound.mp3

Just stream the file as it's downloads, my idea is a MP3 player in Python which opens Soundcloud songs.

Comment: @LevLevitsky I'm creating an GUI application for Soundcloud with Python and Tkinter, and some sounds could be longer than 40 minutes. Which would result in long waiting time, I want something that could stream a sound.

Comment: I would have gone for the vlc media player and use subprocess. It is cross-platform and supports streaming.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [GStreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/) with [python bindings](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/modules/gst-python.html) (requires PyGTK).

Then you can use this code:

```
import pygst
import gst

def on_tag(bus, msg):
    taglist = msg.parse_tag()
    print 'on_tag:'
    for key in taglist.keys():
        print '\t%s = %s' % (key, taglist[key])

#our stream to play
music_stream_uri = 'http://mp3channels.webradio.antenne.de/chillout'

#creates a playbin (plays media form an uri) 
player = gst.element_factory_make("playbin", "player")

#set the uri
player.set_property('uri', music_stream_uri)

#start playing
player.set_state(gst.STATE_PLAYING)

#listen for tags on the message bus; tag event might be called more than once
bus = player.get_bus()
bus.enable_sync_message_emission()
bus.add_signal_watch()
bus.connect('message::tag', on_tag)

#wait and let the music play
raw_input('Press enter to stop playing...')
```

[GStreamer playbin Docs](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-base-plugins/html/gst-plugins-base-plugins-playbin.html)

**UPDATE**

Controlling the player:

```
def play():
    player.set_state(gst.STATE_PLAYING)

def pause():
    player.set_state(gst.STATE_PAUSED)

def stop():
    player.set_state(gst.STATE_NULL)

def play_new_uri( new_uri ):
    player.set_state(gst.STATE_NULL)
    player.set_property('uri', new_uri )
    play()
```

Answer (score 2):

[PyAudio](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/) seems to be what you are looking for. It is a python module that allows you to reproduce and record streamed audio files. It also allows you implement the server.

According PyAudio's site: Runs in GNU/Linux, Microsoft Windows, and Apple Mac OS X.

This is an example I copy from http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/#examples :

```
"""PyAudio Example: Play a WAVE file."""

import pyaudio
import wave
import sys

CHUNK = 1024

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print("Plays a wave file.\n\nUsage: %s filename.wav" % sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(-1)

wf = wave.open(sys.argv[1], 'rb')

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
                channels=wf.getnchannels(),
                rate=wf.getframerate(),
                output=True)

data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)

while data != '':
    stream.write(data)
    data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()

p.terminate()
```

I think you will find [this](http://floppsie.comp.glam.ac.uk/Glamorgan/gaius-/wireless/5.pdf.4) interesting too. And surely brings you some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

[Pygame](http://www.pygame.org/news.html) is a good place to start. Its not perfect by any means, but it does handle sounds, it has a mixer, and midi support as well. It is also cross platform.

Comment: Couldn't find the modules API to playback remote files, but it seems to be a great module!

Comment: Just tried. This does not work, neither with mixer.music nor with a Sound object.