# Decompose Audio stream from Gstreamer in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, signals, signal-processing, gstreamer

When we use pictures in Python codes we can be helped by `PIL` to get RGB values which we can access as a list. I want to do something like that (getting numeric values from given signal) by using GStreamer in Python. I looked in the guide right [here](http://files.majorsilence.com/pygtkbook/pygtk-notebook-latest-0.13.pdf) but he says nothing about saving the signal in the pipeline or getting numeric values from it.

Is Gstreamer able to do it? If so: Can anybody supply me with a short tutorial for getting numerical values from Gstreamer?

Answer (score 1):

Here is come code nicked from another SO answer which plays streaming audio given some URL using python

```
import pygst
import gst

def on_tag(bus, msg):
    taglist = msg.parse_tag()
    print 'on_tag:'
    for key in taglist.keys():
        print '\t%s = %s' % (key, taglist[key])

#our stream to play
music_stream_uri = 'http://mp3channels.webradio.antenne.de/chillout'

#creates a playbin (plays media form an uri) 
player = gst.element_factory_make("playbin", "player")

#set the uri
player.set_property('uri', music_stream_uri)

#start playing
player.set_state(gst.STATE_PLAYING)

#listen for tags on the message bus; tag event might be called more than once
bus = player.get_bus()
bus.enable_sync_message_emission()
bus.add_signal_watch()
bus.connect('message::tag', on_tag)

#wait and let the music play
raw_input('Press enter to stop playing...')
```

[here is the SO answer where this was nicked from](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20631404/147175)

this will get you started ... then its a matter of finding what API call gives you access to the streaming audio buffer

....  [audioread](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/audioread) looks hopeful

from its docs

```
with audioread.audio_open(filename) as f:
    print(f.channels, f.samplerate, f.duration)
    for buf in f:
        do_something(buf)
```

Comment: Thanks. My problem is creating and accessing a read-write buffer. I wonder how to do that? theoretically has to exist option to create a buffer but I couldn't find any example for catching buffer from given source.

Comment: the stock examples may give pointers :  /usr/share/gst-python/0.10/examples

Comment: about audioread: How can I process the variable from gstreamer to it?

Comment: It does not seem like audioread supports reading from a HTTP stream (or any other data which is not a file on disk)