# How to play mp3 from URL

Tags: python, ubuntu, audio

I'm trying to write a python script that will play mp3 from Soundcloud URL

This is what I've already done:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = "soundcloud.com/artist/song.mp3"
u = urlopen(url)

data = u.read(1024)

while data:
   player.play(data)
   data = u.read(1024)
```

I tried `pyaudio` with many options like changing formats, channels, rate.
and I just get strange sound from the speakers, I searched Google for `pyaudio` playing mp3 and didn't found any information.

I tried `pygame` by creating `Sound` object by passing the bytes from the mp3 and then just by executing the play function. I am not getting any errors: the script runs but nothing is playing.

I'm working with Python 3 and Ubuntu.

Comment: I guess you will have to find a way to first download the files as mp3 and then play them as you mentioned with pygame for example. Downloading should be the difficult part however... How would url = "sound_cloud url" look like? Can you give an example? I you had something like url="soundcloud.com/artist/song.mp3" you could simply use: import os; os.system('wget ' + url) but I doubt that the url has this format.

Comment: I need it to be streamed, the url looks like this: "https://ec-media.sndcdn.com/cWHNerOLlkUq.128.mp3?f10880d39085a94a0418a7ef69b03d522cd6dfee9399eeb9a522079b6afcbe3bd34f537531708eb245f81c7e0db701476a167319865dd299cf41501b5895e9caee9e3be93d" any one?

Comment: I get "403 - Forbidden" if I click that url. Are you sure the url is correct?

Comment: it may be possible, but you need first decode the download chunk in PCM data and stream ....

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you happen to have VLC installed (or are willing to install it), then this should work:

```
import vlc
p = vlc.MediaPlayer("http://your_mp3_url")
p.play()
```

This has the advantage that it works with everything VLC works with, not just MP3. It can also be paused if you want to.

You can install vlc for python using

```
pip install python-vlc
```

Answer (score 3):

Sorry but I do not have Python3 to test here, to stream `mp3` using `pyaudio` you will need decode it in PCM data, I know that [pymedia](http://pymedia.org/) can do it, but it is too old and just support `python27`.

To do this the right way you will need to know some attributes of your audio, things like samplerate, number of channels, bit resolution, to set it in the pyaudio.

I can show how I do it using `python27` + `pyaudio`, first I will show how it is done to stream `.wav`

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
#to python3.x
#from urllib.request import urlopen
import pyaudio


pyaud = pyaudio.PyAudio()

srate=44100

stream = pyaud.open(format = pyaud.get_format_from_width(1),
                channels = 1,
                rate = srate,
                output = True)


url = "http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/WAV/NeroSoundTrax/NeroSoundTrax_test4_PCM_Mono_VBR_8SS_44100Hz.wav"
u = urlopen(url)

data = u.read(8192)

while data:

    stream.write(data)
    data = u.read(8192)
```

choose large buffer, python is slow in while loop, i did it using chunks of size `8192`, note that `format`, `channels` and `rate` are the rigth attributes for this `wav` file, so for `.wav` we not need decode, it is a `PCM` data, now for `mp3` we will need decode and put in `PCM` format to stream.

Lets try using `pymedia`

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
import pyaudio
import pymedia.audio.acodec as acodec
import pymedia.muxer as muxer
dm= muxer.Demuxer( 'mp3' )


pyaud = pyaudio.PyAudio()

srate=44100

stream = pyaud.open(format = pyaud.get_format_from_width(2),
                channels = 1,
                rate = srate,
                output = True)


url = "http://www.bensound.org/bensound-music/bensound-dubstep.mp3"

u = urlopen(url)

data = u.read(8192)

while data:

    #Start Decode using pymedia
    dec= None
    s= " "
    sinal=[]
    while len( s ):
        s= data
        if len( s ):
            frames= dm.parse( s )
            for fr in frames:
                if dec== None:
                    # Open decoder
                    dec= acodec.Decoder( dm.streams[ 0 ] )
                r= dec.decode( fr[ 1 ] )
                if r and r.data:
                    din = r.data;
            s=""
    #decode ended

    stream.write(din)
    data = u.read(8192)
```

This may be secret, because I never saw anyone showing how this can be done in python, for python3 I not know anything that can decode .mp3 into pieces like pymedia do.

Here these two codes are streming and working for `.wav` and `.mp3`

Comment: Well that just blew my speakers :/

Answer (score 2):

Check if you can download file manually using that `URL`. If its protected site with username/passwd, you may need to take care of that first.

If not, here is a working code that downloads file from `url` using `urllib2` and then plays it using [pydub](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/).

Its a two step process where first mp3 file is downloaded and saved to file and then played using external player.

```
import urllib2
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play


mp3file = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.bensound.org/bensound-music/bensound-dubstep.mp3")
with open('./test.mp3','wb') as output:
  output.write(mp3file.read())

song = AudioSegment.from_mp3("./test.mp3")
play(song)
```

** Update **
You did mention that you need streaming from web. In that case you may want to look at [GStreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/) with [Python Bindings](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/modules/gst-python.html)

Here is a [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20460296/playing-remote-audio-files-in-python) for that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use python-vlc

```
pip install python-vlc
import vlc as v
mp3 = v.MediaPlayer("file_path_of_mp3")
mp3.play()
```

Answer (score -1):

I try with this code :

```html
import urllib.request   #codigo vale
import IPython.display as ipd
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play


mp3file = urllib.request.urlopen("http://colecciones.humboldt.org.co/rec/sonidos/IAvH-CSA-2/IAvH-CSA-2.mp3")
with open('./test.mp3','wb') as output:
  output.write(mp3file.read())

ipd.Audio('./test.mp3') # salida audio
```