# Play Audio From Url using Python,(Telegram-bot)

Tags: python, audio-streaming, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I have tried many libraries,they didn't work for me:(

```
import pyglet
url=https://api.telegram.org/file/TOKEN/GENERATED_FILE_PATH
pyglet.resource.path = [r'url']
pyglet.resource.reindex()
music = pyglet.resource.media(r'filename.mp3/oga')
player.queue(music)
player.play()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to play mp3 from URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38171169/how-to-play-mp3-from-url)

Answer (score 0):

This question is already answered here:
[How to play mp3 from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38171169/how-to-play-mp3-from-url)

> If you happen to have VLC installed (or are willing to install it), then this should work:
>
> `import vlc
>   p = vlc.MediaPlayer("http://your_mp3_url") 
>   p.play()`
>
> This has the advantage that it works with everything VLC works with, not just MP3. It can also be paused if you want to.

(Oops... Looks like the formatting failed)

Comment: is there any alternative ways to do that?

Comment: Please just google "Python play around from URL". I found only this one