# Play mp3 raw audio data without writing to file

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, mp3, raw-data

I would like to know how I can play mp3 raw audio data (retrieved from Ivona text to speech API) without writing it to a file.

Does I have to convert it to wav and use `pyaudio`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do it:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import pyaudio

pyaud = pyaudio.PyAudio()
srate=44100
stream = pyaud.open(format = pyaud.get_format_from_width(1),
                channels = 1,
                rate = srate,
                output = True)


url = ... # Assuming you retrive audio data from an URL
u = urlopen(url)
data = u.read(8192)

while data:
    stream.write(data)
    data = u.read(8192)
```

For reference, see [How to play mp3 from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38171169/how-to-play-mp3-from-url).

Hope this helps!